# Mix-blend with custom color

Tags: javascript, css

I have a text in black (including some SVG icons) and a purple circle (.ball) that follows the mouse movement. I'm using a mix-blend effect. The color of the text changes when the ball moves over it, which is fine. However, I would like to have this changed color in turquoise (as shown in the second image).
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
div.ball{

width: 140px;
height: 140px;

@media(min-width: 1280px) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

@media(min-width: 1568px) {
    width: 268px;
    height: 268px;
}

background-color: $primary;
border-radius: 50%;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
top: -100px;
left: -100px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
overflow: hidden;
    
mix-blend-mode: exclusion;

filter: invert(1);
}
```

- [Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih4NZ.png)
- [Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKQQS.png)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid CSS. You also tagged this with JavaScript... why? Please see [mcve].

Comment: @TylerH it is actually valid CSS: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/ But I second the remaining of your comment.

Comment: @Kaiido Fair enough, but that spec is a working draft--subject to change and should not be used in production code.